# Slick2d can't draw rectangle with draw function

Tags: java, lwjgl, game-engine, slick2d

I am just starting out with `slick2d` so this is definitely a beginner question.
I am trying to draw a simple rectangle, but if I initialize it before drawing it, for example: `g.draw(myRectangle)`, I get an error :-

> The method `draw(Shape)` in the type Graphics is not applicable for the arguments (Rectangle).

If I tried to define it as a Shape and initlialize it as a rectangle, like so:

```
Shape startButton;

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {   
    startButton = new Rectangle(600, 100, 200, 50);
}
```

I get this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Rectangle to Shape

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you import the correct rectangle class? You might have imported the shape from slick2d but the rectangle from awt or javafx.

Comment: @Selim Yes that fixed it, thanks a lot!